# How to store files in Android's cache directory?

Tags: java, android, mobile

My goal is store temporary files in the directory returned by Context#getCacheDir().

```
/data/data/my.app/cache/somedir/foo.json
```

I presume I can just use java.io apis to write files there. But I'm not sure how to set permissions on files there because I would not be able to use Context#MODE_PRIVATE.

The filename parameter to Context#openFileOutput and Context#openFileInput cannot accept input with path delimiters. Thus they are only useful for files created in directory:

```
/data/data/my.app
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each application in Android runs under it's own user account by default, so files created by your app would not be accessible from any other app.  Check out bullet point #3 at the top of this page:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html

You could also verify this by running a shell in your emulator/device and looking at the output of ls -l.

Answer (score 5):

> But I'm not sure how to set
>   permissions on files there because I
>   would not be able to use
>   Context#MODE_PRIVATE.

AFAIK, they should be private by default.