# Clean music application cache - android

Tags: java, android, caching

I need to clean music cache programatically. I know, that one way is to getcontext of that application, for example com.htc.music, and then getCacheDir and delete it, but I don't know how. Second option is to map File variable with the path data/data/com.htc.music/cache and then delete the subdirectories but it doesnt work. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Are you storing your data in Application Data?
If so, you can delete it in your activity: YourActivity.this.deleteFile(filename);

Comment: No, I want in my own application clean cache of other applications.

Comment: Then, check the answer in this topic
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628677/how-to-store-files-in-androids-cache-directory